# My code is not returning the value from function

Tags: python-3.x, return-value, tail-recursion

I have recently started to code in Python. While trying to solve a problem statement I encountered this issue where my code does not return the value. The code is to continue adding all the digits in the number given, until you get a value less than or equal to 9.

**Example** : 12345->1+2+3+4+5=15. 15 is greater than 9 so 1+5=6. 6 is less than 9 so 6 should be returned.
Here's the code:

```
def uno(num):
    temp=str(num)
    sum1=0
    for x in temp:
        sum1=sum1+int(x)
    print(sum1)
    if sum1<=9:
        return sum1
    else:
        uno(sum1)

result=uno(12345)
print(result)

Output:
15
6
None
```

The output I get is 'None'. I tried to debug using "print(sum1)". The value is stored as expected.
Can you please tell me where I made a mistake.

Comment: Return the result of the recursive call: `else: return uno(sum1)`

Answer (score 1):

You forgot a `return` statement:

```
def uno(num):
    temp = str(num)
    sum1 = 0
    for x in temp:
        sum1 = sum1+int(x)
    if sum1 <= 9:
        return sum1
    else:
        return uno(sum1)


result = uno(12345)
print(result)
```

#### Output

```
6
```

Answer (score 0):

In the else statement,
write:

```
return(uno(sum1))
```